# How do I find out if this mobile tower is bad for my health?

Tags: electromagnetic, radiation

I don't know if this would be on-topic here, but please feel free to migrate this question if that's not the case. I have this mobile tower very close to my house. This photo was taken from my top-floor. It's 15-20 meters away at most.

[image]

I am naturally worried about the electromagnetic radiation I'm exposed to. I was hence wondering whether buying a EMF detector would help me find out whether I am safe or not.

Will an EMF detector help me see the radiation emitted by the tower? Would [this](http://www.amazon.in/NEW-HTC-INSTRUMENTS-EMF-Supertronics1989/dp/B0142MOPPM/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1459876196&sr=1-1&keywords=emf%20meter) do it? What kind of readings would be normal?

Comment: We don't know the wattage of the tower, or if it is directional, or what locale you are in (which affects things like frequencies used and exposure limit laws.) But inverse-square law and an assumption of double-digit wattage says you are going to be fine. That device can't see mobile frequencies as far as I can tell.

Comment: 1) And if you knew the fieldstregth was xx V/m at yy MHz, what would that tell you ? 2) there is no, below xx is safe, above it is unsafe 3) some people are sensitive to EM waves, most are not 4)  EM waves degrade in power with r^3 over distance, you mobile phone probably gives you more EM waves as it is much closer to your body. 5) EM waves are **non ionizing** making them much safer than for example UV light of X-rays.

Comment: And the device you suggest is for **static** magnetic fields, not RF EM fields. The only way to detect the fieldstrength properly is with a RF power meter (expensive) or a spectrum analyser (if you have to ask how expensive, you cannot afford one).

Comment: OP, if you want some fascinating (well, fascinating for some) reading, take a look at http://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/smt-gst.nsf/eng/sf01904.html and friends. Basically, after all these years, the advice is "don't run compliant equipment at full wattage for extended times near parts of your body most made up of water". In this case, "near" is measured in centimeters.

Comment: @jdv I live in India and from what I can tell, it has pretty stringent laws.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, do you have a source for the (non-ionizing) EM sensitivity? Best I've seen are studies showing that those who claim EM sensitivity cannot differentiate between a sham test and the real thing. Showing that they are indeed suffering from something, but not directly linked to EM radiation. Just curious, always open to new info.

Comment: @SamparkSharma, to answer the question in your title, that device would not be a good investment, because measuring RF fields takes a fair amount of know-how, maths, and specialized equipment.

Comment: @JarrodChristman Ionizing versus non-ionizing radiation, look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum  Look at the top, table on the right where it says: **ionizing radiation** Only the high-frequency, high-energy waves are ionizing because they are the only types of radiation which contain enough energy to ionize. As you can see only (extreme) UV, X-rays and Gamma rays are ionizing. Also note how the energy content per quanta of **visible light** is higher than that of radio waves !!!

Comment: Thanks for the comment @fakemoustsche, though I am referencing this comment in particular, "some people are sensitive to EM waves, most are not." Everyone is sensitive to ionizing radiation, but as far as I know, it has not been proven anyone is sensitive to non-ionizing radiation.

Comment: @SamparkSharma I'd just like to point out a very powerful and yet not fully researched problem with cell-phone towers and other "harmful radiation sources". It's called [nocebo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocebo) effect, the opposite of placebo effect. Do read the article.

Comment: To sum it up, people that fear radio and live near radio-installations will feel bad due to radio installations not because the installation itself and EM waves are causing harm, but because deep down, the person himself is convinced that the installation is bad and is causing harm and then this psychological effect itself is the source of problems. Unfortunately, we engineers can make the radios safe, but we alone can't fix the public fear and damage from nocebo effect.

Comment: I doubt they would have put it where they put it its operation would have caused any harm to any one near it?

Comment: There are actually advantages to living and working near cell towers. Cell phones use closed loop power control - the cell tower tells the phone what transmit power to use, and continually adjusts this to keep the receive power at the cell site constant, limiting interference between signals from different phones. The result of this is that your phone (which you might be holding next to your ear) transmits with less power the closer you are to the tower, decreasing your exposure to EM radiation from your phone while also extending the phone's battery life.

Answer (score 10):

No, it would not be a good investment. The device you linked to is designed to detect power-line frequencies (50 Hz or 60 Hz). There are more advanced devices, but as the [Amazon comments](http://smile.amazon.com/Trifield-100XE-EMF-Meter/product-reviews/B00050WQ1G/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_summary?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=helpful) make clear, the demand for them is based on fear and ignorance. The item description refers to "EM pollution" and says that you can use the meter to do "prudent avoidance", but takes it for granted that those are real things. This is clearly designed to scare people into buying a useless (but expensive) product. It's like Monster Cable or those $10,000 oxygen-free speaker wires.

To emphasize what a joke these detecters are, the other main use for them is ghost hunting. (Seriously. [*Ghost hunting.*](http://smile.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R6EH7O0A2U2AT/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00050WQ1G) Give me a break.)

Meanwhile, here's what the American Cancer Society [has to say](http://www.cancer.org/cancer/cancercauses/othercarcinogens/athome/cellular-phone-towers) about cell phone towers and cancer:

> **Do cellular phone towers cause cancer?**
>
> Some people have expressed concern that living, working, or going to school near a cell phone tower might increase the risk of cancer or other health problems. At this time, there is very little evidence to support this idea. In theory, there are some important points that would argue against cellular phone towers being able to cause cancer.
>
> First, the energy level of radiofrequency (RF) waves is relatively low, especially when compared with the types of radiation that are known to increase cancer risk, such as gamma rays, x-rays, and ultraviolet (UV) light. The energy of RF waves given off by cell phone towers is not enough to break chemical bonds in DNA molecules, which is how these stronger forms of radiation may lead to cancer.
>
> A second issue has to do with wavelength. RF waves have long wavelengths, which can only be concentrated to about an inch or two in size. This makes it unlikely that the energy from RF waves could be concentrated enough to affect individual cells in the body.
>
> Third, even if RF waves were somehow able to affect cells in the body at higher doses, the level of RF waves present at ground level is very low – well below the recommended limits. Levels of energy from RF waves near cell phone towers are not significantly different from the background levels of RF radiation in urban areas from other sources, such as radio and television broadcast stations.
>
> For these reasons, most scientists agree that cell phone antennas or towers are unlikely to cause cancer.

There's also talk about directionality:

> **How are people exposed to the energy from cellular phone towers?**
>
> As people use cell phones to make calls, signals are transmitted back and forth to the base station. The RF waves produced at the base station are given off into the environment, where people can be exposed to them.
>
> The energy from a cellular phone tower antenna, like that of other telecommunication antennas, is directed toward the horizon (parallel to the ground), with some downward scatter. Base station antennas use higher power levels than other types of land-mobile antennas, but much lower levels than those from radio and television broadcast stations. The amount of energy decreases rapidly as the distance from the antenna increases. As a result, the level of exposure to radio waves at ground level is very low compared to the level close to the antenna.
>
> Public exposure to radio waves from cell phone tower antennas is slight for several reasons. The power levels are relatively low, the antennas are mounted high above ground level, and the signals are transmitted intermittently, rather than constantly.
>
> At ground level near typical cellular base stations, the amount of RF energy is thousands of times less than the limits for safe exposure set by the US Federal Communication Commission (FCC) and other regulatory authorities. It is very unlikely that a person could be exposed to RF levels in excess of these limits just by being near a cell phone tower.
>
> When a cellular antenna is mounted on a roof, it is possible that a person on the roof could be exposed to RF levels greater than those typically encountered on the ground. But even then, exposure levels approaching or exceeding the FCC safety guidelines are only likely to be found very close to and directly in front of the antennas. If this is the case, access to these areas should be limited.
>
> The level of RF energy inside buildings where a base station is mounted is typically much lower than the level outside, depending on the construction materials of the building. Wood or cement block reduces the exposure level of RF radiation by a factor of about 10. The energy level behind an antenna is hundreds to thousands of times lower than in front. Therefore, if an antenna is mounted on the side of a building, the exposure level in the room directly behind the wall is typically well below the recommended exposure limits.

I wouldn't worry about the cell phone tower. If you want to worry about your health, maybe start by looking at the [top 10 causes of death in India](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjotL7Vh_jLAhUMQSYKHQR-Aj4QFggrMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cdc.gov%2Fglobalhealth%2Fcountries%2Findia%2Fpdf%2Findia.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFH_OVLf4qERl5iufZLFWmov9wxbg&sig2=ShHa2q_X4rFFtUVk888oXw):

> 1. Ischaemic heart disease 12%
> 2. Chronic obstructive pulmonary disease (lung disease) 11%
> 3. Stroke 9%
> 4. Diarrheal disease 6%
> 5. Lower respiratory infections 5%
> 6. Preterm birth complications 4%
> 7. Tuberculosis 3%
> 8. Self-inflicted injuries 3%
> 9. Falls 3%
> 10. Road injury 2%

Avoid tobacco smoke, exercise, take care of your mental health, and be careful near roads and ledges. That'll get you a lot farther than worrying about non-ionizing radiation.

Comment: To be fair, the scaremongering about EMF isn't quality of life, but rather quality. The unfounded worry is that modern life causes all sorts of low-grade problems that may lead to serious conditions, but are clustered around variations of feeling sick or tired. But, point taken about actual death risks.

Comment: @jdv Yeah, there's a full spectrum from "electrosensitivity" all the way up to "OMG CANCER!!!1!". Anyone who wants to know more about that should probably ask on the Skeptics SE.

Answer (score 5):

Distance is your friend.

15 to 20 meters may sound close, but signals will drop a lot in that distance.  Let's compare this with a cell phone you might hold next to your head — suppose 1.5 to 2.0 cm.  In this case, the tower would be 1000 times further.

Since power drops with the square of distance, a signal from a cellular phone at the tower would arrive at your head roughly 1000 <sup>2</sup>  or 1 million times less in power than the one in your hand.  Of course the tower is probably transmitting to dozens of phones, perhaps hundreds using several bands.  However, even if its combined emissions are 1000 times stronger, they would still hit your head 1000 times weaker than your phone.

Of course the factor of 2 is a far-field approximation, so your phone may actually be hitting you with even a higher percentage.

So if you want to be worried, hang up your phone, but don't worry about the tower :)

Comment: That's actually very relaxing to hear. :) Did you see the attached photo? It really is pretty close and not very tall, which adds to my worries. Luckily, I sleep and do most of my stuff one floor down. Also, EF hasn't been proven to cause health damage, right? This is a 'better be safe than sorry' kinda thing?

Comment: Yup, my calculations were based on clear line of site.  If you have a wall and/or ceiling too, those signals will probably be another factor of 10 lower.  And @FakeMoustache makes a great point - EM waves are non ionizing making them much safer than for example UV light of X-rays

Answer (score 2):

The signal from cell site antennas is mostly aimed horizontally, so most of it will be passing directly over your head.

Your position 20 m from the tower probably receives less signal than someone 200 m away, directly in the line of the beam.

Look at these patterns, (swiped from [here](http://www.emss.co.za/3d-modeling-simulation.php) with apologies ):
[image: Cell site with patterns]

Here the orange indicates a zone which a trained person should not enter, and the yellow indicates the zone which is above the limits specified for the general public.

You can clearly see how narrow the beams are. In your direction, the public safetly limit is perhaps 1 metre from the antenna, so you're 20 x further.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring electromagnetic fields is complex, as is quantifying the biological risks of exposure. This report contains relevant information:
"Report to Canadian Board of Health: Outcome of The International Conference of Cell Tower Siting" (2000)

https://www1.toronto.ca/city_of_toronto/toronto_public_health/healthy_public_policy/hphe/files/pdf/cell_tower_conference.pdf

"…current evidence suggests that there is no threshold below which there are no effects of radio frequencies on human health. … It is recommended that: The Board of Health recommend to Health Canada that public exposure limits for radio frequency fields… be made 100 times more strict as previously recommended…"